# Como actualizar valor de um campo da linha de documento na V9?

Tags: c#

Estava vendo exemplos de códigos da V10 e encontrei isso,

```
 // Add new line to the invoice and set all the item related information.
 PriEngine.Engine.Vendas.Documentos.AdicionaLinha(invoice, item.SubItems[0].Text, ref qtd);
 linhas = invoice.Linhas;
 linhas.GetEdita(1).Desconto1 = 10;
```

Gostaria de atingir o mesmo resultado utilizando os interops da V9, de modo que consiga actualizar o campo CCusto das linhas de um documento de compra.

Alguém sabe como posso proceder? obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde, pode ser feito assim:

```
PriEngine.BSO.Comercial.Compras.AdicionaLinha(invoice, "A0001", 1);
invoice.get_Linhas()[1].set_CCustoCBL("valor");
```

Comment: Obrigado! Funcionou